# Order of composition when dealing with transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, function-and-relation-composition

I have been struggling with a question in my book.

- $T$ is a translation of $(+5,+4)$,
- $M$ is a reflection in the line $y=x$.
- $R$ is a 90 degree anticlockwise rotation about $(0,0)$

> Write down the coordinates of the image of the point (7,9) under the following transformations:

- TR - to get the correct answer, I had to rotate first then translate.
- RT - to get the correct answer, I had to translate first then rotate.

Did the guys who made the answer key get mixed up?

Another doubt: When asked to feed (7,9) into transformation TM, the answer is (-7,9), which is highly suspect IMO-regardless of order I should NOT get any negative numbers via multiplication, as the matrix for reflection has all positive numbers- when I worked out reflection followed by translation, I got (15,11).

So, for a transformation AB, do you apply B first then A? And in the second case, did I get mixed up again or did the answer key get it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are dealing are affine transformations in the plane, i.e. transformations of the form:
$$
\vec{y}=A \vec{x}+\vec{t}
$$
where $A$ is a $2 \times2$ real matrix:
$$
A=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 a & b\\
 c & d
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
 and $\vec{t}$ is a vector representing  the translation. In your case:
$$
\vec{t}=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 t_1\\
 t_2
\end {array} 
\right]
=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 5\\
 4
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix) such transformations can be represented by $3 \times 3$ matrices of the form:
$$ M=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 a&b & t_1\\
 c & d & t_2\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
that operates as the usual rows-columns product rule, giving:
$$
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 y_1\\
 y_2\\
 1
\end {array} 
\right]=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 a&b & t_1\\
 c & d & t_2\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 x_1\\
 x_2\\
 1
\end {array} 
\right]
=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 ax_1+bx_2+t_1\\
 cx_1+dx_2+t_2\\
 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
Where we have add a third component $1$ to the vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

In your case you have:
$$ 
T=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 0&0 &5\\
 0& 0 & 4\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
\qquad
R=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 0&-1 &0\\
 1& 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
\qquad
M=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 0&1 &0\\
 1& 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
For combining two transformation you have to calculate the product of their matrices and we know that the product of matrices is not commutative, so that  e.g. $TR \ne RT$ ( as you can be easily test).

Multiplying the given matrices with the given vector 
$$
\mathbf{v}=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 7\\
 9\\
 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
**in the right order** you can easily find the answers to all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order of $AB$ is usually $B$ then $A$. It's like a composite function $f\circ g(x)$, you apply $g$ first, then $f$. The answer of that next problem should be $(14,11)$.