# Order in which to multiply these matrices

Tags: matrices

I am trying to compute a rotation matrix to rotate something about a point $(1, 0.5)$ by 90 degrees.

$$a = \pmatrix{1&0&1\\0&1&0.5\\0&0&1}$$
$$b = \pmatrix{0&-1&0\\1&0&1\\0&0&1}$$
$$c = \pmatrix{1&0&-1\\0&1&-0.5\\0&0&1}$$

$$p_1 = (1,0,1)$$

What order should the matrices be multiplied to rotate $p_1$ to get the answer $(1.5,0.5)$.

I have tried many different ways but cannot get the answer. I have the question/answer but am trying to understand how to actually get there

Comment: Your question is confused.  You say that $p_1$ has three coordinate, but the other points $(1.5,0.5)$ and $(1,0.5)$ have only two coordinate. So, You are in a three dimensional space  where matrice represent linear transformations or in a two dimensional space with affine matrices?

Comment: p1 is a vertex of a triangle. The triangle itself is 2d, but to multiply by the matrices I need it in 3x1 format. The triangle is being rotated about a point (1, 0.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using matrices that represent affine transformations in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( see my answer to [Order of composition when dealing with transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134556/order-of-composition-when-dealing-with-transformations/1134673#1134673)
).

The rotation  of $90°$ about the point $A\equiv(1,0.5)$ is given by:
$ TRT^{-1} $ where: $T^{-1}$ translate the origin to the poin $A$,  $R$ is the matrix representing the rotation of $90°$ about the (new) origin, and $T$ return all to the old origin.

$T$ is your matrix $a$, $T^{-1}$ is your matrix $c$ but your $b$ is wrong. The matrix representing the rotation is
$$
R=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 0&-1 &0\\
 1& 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0& 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
Now if you perform the product $TRT^{-1} v$ with 
$$
v=
\left[
\begin {array}{ccccc}
 1\\
 0\\
 1
\end {array} 
\right]
$$
 you have the right result.

Comment: Thanks the typo in b was throwing me off. I understand this now.